# Is there a natural way to bijectively correspond connection on vector bundle and principal connection on its frame bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, fiber-bundles, connections

Is there a natural construction of $G$-connection $\omega^*$ on the frame bundle $P$ given a covariant derivative $\nabla$ defined on a vector bundle $\pi_E:E\to M$?(The structure group $G$ here is then general linear group on vector bundle fiber)

Since $\nabla$ differs from $d$ by a form $\omega\in \Omega^1(M,End(E)=ad(P))$, we can pullback $\omega$ to $\omega^*\in\Omega^1(P,ad(P))$ by projection $\pi_P:P\to M$. Now,given a basis $e_1,...,e_n$ of lie algebra $end(E)$, we can find the associated fundamental vector fields $e_i^*$ and the dual 1-forms $\epsilon_i^*$. Define an $end(E)-$ valued 1-form $\omega_0= \sum \epsilon_i\otimes e_i$ on $P$ then $\omega_0$ will give back lie algebra element from its fundamental vector field. I then think the $G-$equivariant principal connection form on $P$ must be $\omega_0+\omega^*$ where $\omega^*=0$ corresponding to flat-connection. However, there seems to be the problem of showing that the said $\omega^*$ is $G-$equivariant.

Am I on the right track, or is there more natural ways to construct the principal connection on $P$ from $\omega$? I'll be delighted if someone could help me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried writing $\nabla$ with respect to a $G$-frame?

Comment: Wouldn't that be same as obtaining the said form $\omega$?

Comment: Oh you mean something like writing $\nabla(X_i)(S_j)=\Gamma^{k}_{i,j}S_k$ and using the transformation rule for $\Gamma^{k}_{i,j}$ to show that the constructed $\omega^*$ is ad-type?

Comment: I meant to choose a $G$-frame $S_i$ and write $\nabla S_i = \sum \omega^j_i\otimes S_j$. Then $\omega = (\omega^j_i)$ should be a $\mathfrak g$-valued $1$-form. What are the transformation rules when you change frame?

Comment: Ah okay. Given two frames $A$ and $B$ and corresponding connection forms $\omega_A$ and $\omega_B$, I get $\omega_A(B)=B\omega_A+dB$, or equivalently $ad(B^{-1})\omega_A=\omega_B+BdB^{-1}$ which does give me the wanted G-equivariance. Then adding pullback of $\omega$ to the constructed $\omega_0$ will be sufficient right? I guess I was too obsessed with methods that didn't need coordinates.

Comment: I didn't read your question too carefully, I admit. It would help if you edited to say $\omega\in\Omega^1(M,End(E))$ in the first part of the first sentence in the second paragraph. I missed your saying that $\nabla$ was given by $\omega$.

Comment: Are there any other changes to make?

Comment: I haven't thought about it ...

Comment: What is $G$ here?  Is it the structure group of the vector bundle $E \to M$? If so, then presumably you're taking the connection $\nabla$ on $E$ to be $G$-compatible in some sense?

Comment: I made the changes. Sorry for being inexplicit. The $G$ here corresponds to the structure group of the frame bundle $P$, the genearl linear group on the fiber of the vector space.